# KeyListener not responding in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, keylistener

I wrote this code for very simple pong and everything works well except I just can't figure out how to make KeyListener work. I don't know where to put the Listener or how to use it. Any other tips are welcome, I am a noob so please explain to that level.

```
package pong;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pong extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{   
    int border = 15;

    int enemyScore = 0;
    int playerScore = 0;

    int ballx = 248;
    int bally = 170;

    int playerx = 482;
    double playery = 162;
    int playeryy = 162;

    int enemyx = 0;
    double enemyy = 162;
    int enemyyy = 162;

    boolean gameReset = true;

    boolean down;
    boolean right;

    //ball movement
    private void moveBall()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        while (gameReset == true)
        {
            ballx = 240;
            bally = 170;
            down = rand.nextBoolean();
            right = rand.nextBoolean();
            gameReset = false;
        }

        if (right == true)
        {
            ballx++;
        }
        else
        {
            ballx--;
        }

        if (down == true)
        {
            bally++;
        }
        else
        {
            bally--;
        }

        if(bally == getHeight()-border)
        {
            down = false;
        }
        else if (bally == 0)
        {
            down = true;
        }

        if (playeryy < bally+14 && playeryy+59 > bally && ballx == 468)
        {
            right = false;
        } 
        else if (ballx == getWidth()-border)
        {
            gameReset = true;
            enemyScore ++;
        }
        else if (enemyyy < bally+14 && enemyyy+59 > bally && ballx == 13)
        {
            right = true;
        } 
        else if (ballx == 0)
        {
            gameReset = true;
            playerScore ++;
        }
    }


    //enemy movement
    private void moveEnemy()
    {
        if (right == false && bally > enemyy+8 && enemyy < 294)
        {
            enemyy += 0.8;
            enemyyy = (int) enemyy;
        }
        else if (right == false && bally < enemyy+8 && enemyy > 0)
        {
            enemyy -= 0.8;
            enemyyy = (int) enemyy;
        }
    }

    //Drawing
    @Override                               
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillRect(enemyx, enemyyy, 15, 60);
        g.fillRect(playerx, playeryy, 15, 60);
        g.fill3DRect(ballx, bally, 15, 15, true);
        System.out.println("Enemy Score: " + enemyScore + " Player Score: "+ playerScore);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("p0ng");                      //makes new frame
        frame.setSize(512,384);                                 //sets the size
        frame.setVisible(true);                                 //makes it visble
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //allows it to sleep
        Pong game = new Pong();
        frame.add(game);

        while(true)
        {
            game.moveBall();
            game.moveEnemy();
            game.repaint();

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }     
    }  

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        //not being used
    }

    //Player movement
     @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {  
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && playery < 294)
        {
            playery += .8;
            playeryy = (int) playery;
        }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && playery > 0)
        {
            playery -= .8;
            playeryy = (int) playery;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        //not being used
    }
}
```

Comment: You newer add the keylistener to your frame

Comment: where do I add that?

Comment: You can using Frame.addKeyListener(game)

Comment: When the provided answers "some times" work, take a look at how to fix them properly with [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Any other tips are welcome

- Don't use `KeyListener`, it's too unreliable, especially when there are better options available. Start by having a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- As a generally rule of thumb, you should override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- You're violating the single thread rules of Swing and risking race conditions between you core logic and the UI. Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a simple solution
- Your "main" loop is setup wrong.  Each iteration of the loop should update the current state that needs to be painted. You shouldn't be using "holding" loops to "pause" the state, but instead use `if` statements to block out the sections you need/don't need to execute based on the current state

Comment: Can you show me how it would look with this code. I'm having a hard time understanding how to use Key Binding

Comment: [Key bindings example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984912/java-key-bindings-not-working/17984949#17984949)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Pong(){
addKeyListner(this);
}
```

you need to register your `panel` to the `keyListner`.
you can use `addKeyListner` method to do it, since you have implemented `Keylistner` to the same `class` . you can use `this` keyword.you can do this within the `constructor`.

Comment: *"this is a wrong answer."* - so is this. While it "might" work, it's unreliable and as a generally, `KeyListener` is a poor choice, especially when more reliable solutions exist

Comment: i have no idea why do you say that `KeyListener` is a poor choice can u tell me why.

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice because it's unreliable. It will only trigger events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus, since the OP's code meets neither of these constraints, it will continue to fail to work. Even if they do make the component focusable and are able to focus the component, it doesn't take much for focus to be changed and the whole thing breaks again

Comment: well `jPanel` is `isFocusable` by default , but it is a good choice to move with `KeyBindings` instead of key listner . this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java explains why we should use KeyBindings. thanks @MadProgrammer that was really helpful