# Trying to get KeyBindings to work

Tags: java, jcomponent

I am trying to get a simple KeyBindings program to work. I followed the instructions from java doc, and tried to test the stuff answered in this ([Java Key Bindings Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984912/java-key-bindings-not-working)) thread, but i just cant get it to work. I want to output "test" to the console when "F1" is pressed. Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("shit");
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
jPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"), "focus");
jPanel.getActionMap().put("focus", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
});

frame.add(jPanel);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.
2. If that doesn't work then use a different InputMap. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How Key Bindings Work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#maps) to see how the 3 different InputMaps are used.