# Move a graphics object with arrow keys in a draw path

Tags: java, swing, graphics, path, jframe

How do I make arrow keys move a drawn object on a drawn path (for example `drawPolygon()`) right and left in a `JFrame`?

Comment: What did you try? [How to ask....](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: see ho to create key bindings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984912/java-key-bindings-not-working/17984949#17984949 (and learn how to use search ^_^)